# Can not keep the value of select box

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I try to keep the value of dropbox after reload page code is

```
<select name="slLimit" class="slLimitCl" id="limited_num" onchange="selectedTheChoice()">
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
    <option value="0">All</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="selectedValue" name="selectedValue" value="<s:property value="limited_num"/>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedValue = $("#selectedValue").val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
    $("#limited_num").val(selectedValue);
});

function selectedTheChoice(){
    var code = $("#hidden_bunrui_code").val();
    loadAjaxData(code);
}
```

when the selectedTheChoice() return no data the

```
console.log(selectedValue);
```

show right value of dropbox and can keep the selected value

but when

```
selectedTheChoice()
```

return data. the

```
console.log(selectedValue);
```

show undefined and i can not keep the value of dropbox. It return to the first value

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried to use a cookie to store the value?

Comment: Thanks but in this case i cannot use cookie or session

Comment: If you can add a hash tag to the url (`#selectedValue`) you can parse that on page load. See `backbone.js` router for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store that selected value in session.Then you can access after refresh the page.Otherwise you can not access client side data after refresh the page

Comment: Then you can use local storage concept